# Service Version update required?

Tags: android, authentication, xamarin, google-plus, google-play-services

I am working on Xamarin Android Application.I am getting `ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED, resolution=null, message=null` when I try to log in through Google plus in my application.What does this mean? How can I solve this?

Comment: This is not duplicate. The correct answer is to update Play Store, not adding meta tags to the manifest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This message indicates that you need to update Google Play Servcies:

The message from [ConnectionResult](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult?hl=en)

> The installed version of Google Play services is out of date

[Google Play services in Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms&hl=en)

Comment: How can I update Google Play Services?.I have tried to search about it but did't get it

Comment: Well, use Google play store, and upadte to the latest version

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms&hl=en

Comment: To update play store to latest, go to the installed "Play Store" app > Settings > click the version number. It will then show modal dialog to download to latest version.

Comment: Sorry @UdiIdan, but I'm not sure that's how it's done for Xamarin. I haven't been able to make that work, anyway - do you have any insights into how it should be done for this specific technology?