# Google Play services API client can't connect: SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm trying to connect to Google Play services. It used to work perfectly a few months ago, and now I'm getting my `onConnectionFailed` method to invoke with error code `SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED`.

Pretty self explanatory, yet I'm already on the latest version:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.6.1'
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: i think you need to use lower version of  playservice in gradle dependency. so it work on higher version. try 7.3.0 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, just figured out that I also need to update an app on the device called "Google Play Services" for my app to work (and weird enough, it's not even even found when I search Google Play, I had to use the link at the answer on [Service Version update required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33477587/service-version-update-required)).

Updated it and now my app works.
Absolutely ridiculous. I really wonder whose idea was making software components dependent on other apps.

Anyway, problem "solved".